# How can I get alerts for my Google API usage?

Tags: google-api, alert, google-console-developer

This week my API stopped making requests to the Google API, see the usage graph below:

[image: google console usage graph]

Is there a way I can setup alerts on the data that is reported to me in the above graph?

- Alert me when usage is below a threshold?
- Alert me when usage is above a threshold?
- Alert me when we encounter an error of X type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for the Google Developer console sadly the only thing that is close would be the [Google Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/) which doesn't give you the information you are looking for.

There is also no alert within the Google Developer console.   That being said this is an awesome idea.   In the upper right hand corer of the Google developer console there is a speech bubble with an i in it.  Click on it and send feedback.  Google does listen to feed back from developers lets request a notification feature.